# Visualizing object hierarchies in C#

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

Is there any way, given an object reference, to understand "Which live objects hold a reference to this object as a field?" (or any other reference for that matter).

Outputting it in a graphical manner can be nice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a MemoryProfiler.

There are some free and some commercial ones.

I use ANTS Memory Profiler and won't miss it any more.
You can see what are the connections that are holding objects alive.

Also you can make multiple snapshots and then compare them afterwards, too see what objects are new, how has the count of all objects changed and so on.

Here's a small [walktrhough](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough)

see [Product Webpage](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

[image: Retention Graph]

Comment: What i need is the ability to set a breakpoint, at a given code region, and see which object is holding a reference to the object that is currently executing some method. Is this possible using a profiler ?

Comment: @liortal I agree with Boas that you're probably better off using a modern profiler than the debugger to do this. You can wait until the breakpoint is hit, then take a snapshot. I haven't used ANTS but I know that the [SciTech Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) lets you see fields of the objects, so you can use it to find that one instance you care about, and then it can show you an object graph for just that one instance.